# PayPal Sandbox account in Demo Portal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are building a demo website for clients . The moto is to showcase all the functionalities of a real time website . We have added PayPal as one of the checkout method .Since it is a demo portal, there is no point in making the payment live . Is it legal to provide the Sandbox test account publicly on the website so that users can test the payment functionalities ?

Thanks